# Cropping image after pasting it into Excel

Tags: excel, vba, image, file, crop

Below is what I've tried in Excel VBA. It works well pasting the image into Excel, but I need them to be cropped.

The code below represents the attempt:

```
Option Explicit

Sub PDF_To_Excel()
Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")
Dim pdf_path As String
Dim excel_path As String

pdf_path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.PDF), *.PDF", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")

excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value

Dim objFile As File
Dim sPath As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File
Set objFile = fso.GetFile(pdf_path)
sPath = Left(objFile.Path, Len(objFile.Path) - Len(objFile.Name))
Set fo = fso.GetFolder(sPath)
Dim wa As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim wr As Object

Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
'Dim wa As New Word.Application
wa.Visible = False
'Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet
'Dim wr As Word.Range

For Each f In fo.Files
    Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
    Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    wr.WholeStory

    Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
    Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)
    wr.Copy
    nsh.Paste

    Dim oILS As InlineShape
    Set oILS = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
    With oILS
        .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 100
        .PictureFormat.CropTop = 100
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = 100
        .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 100
    End With
    With oILS
        .LockAspectRatio = True
    '    .Height = 260
    '    .Width = 450
    End With

    nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))

    doc.Close True
    nwb.Close True

Next

wa.Quit
End Sub
```

I get this error:

> "Run time error 438 object doesn't support this property or method"

on the following line:

```
Set oILS = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
```

It currently gets the PDFs converted into Word documents and then pastes them into Excel files. But I need the images to be cropped in all the Excel files.

Comment: I think your problem is that the `InlineShapes` object is a Word object. So using it to reference something in an Excel-file might not work.

Comment: Hey, I don't see you selecting anything before the line referencing a selection. Maybe you can change the line that is giving you trouble, to avoid the use of `".selection"` ?  Also inlineshapes does not work for me in Excel, Excels compiler does not recognize it? Dunno if thats my fault tho. Anyway, does `Set oILS = nsh.Shapes(1)` work?

Comment: @Beek I put the Reference to MS Office 16.0 Object from Tools, and still have the same problem. Any other ideas?

Comment: My comment had a suggestion to change the .selection line to something that references the first shape. But for a more readable example, see my "answer". I think we just need to find a good way to reference the picture you added. The way to reference it depends on your needs. But I think referencing the last shape on your excel sheet might work?

Comment: I don't think the reference matters in this case. Your selection is in Excel, so it's an Excel-object (range or shape probably). And that Excel-object doesn't have a property or method called `InlineShapes`, because that's a property belonging to a Word-object.

Comment: @Beek right, thanks! Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @nytro: I think @Czeskleba has the right answer for you below. If you change your `dim oILS As InlineShape` to `dim oILS As Shape`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added a picture to a word document, then copied it over manually to excel. And just changing the dim to shape and the reference that was giving you trouble kinda worked on my end. I am having trouble reproducing the first half of your code, making a pdf into a word document and getting a copyable picture to show up. This is probably because of adobe/office version differences tho and I don't have the time to remake the whole setup, I'm sorry. See the suggestions in the comments in the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub PDF_To_Excel()
Dim setting_sh As Worksheet
Set setting_sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setting")
Dim pdf_path As String
Dim excel_path As String

pdf_path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="PDF Files (*.PDF), *.PDF", Title:="Select File To Be Opened")

excel_path = setting_sh.Range("E12").Value

Dim objFile As File
Dim sPath As String
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fo As Folder
Dim f As File
Set objFile = fso.GetFile(pdf_path)
sPath = Left(objFile.Path, Len(objFile.Path) - Len(objFile.Name))
Set fo = fso.GetFolder(sPath)
Dim wa As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim wr As Object

Set wa = CreateObject("word.application")
'Dim wa As New Word.Application
wa.Visible = False
'Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim nsh As Worksheet
'Dim wr As Word.Range

For Each f In fo.Files
    Set doc = wa.documents.Open(f.Path, False, Format:="PDF Files")
    Set wr = doc.Paragraphs(1).Range
    wr.WholeStory

    Set nwb = Workbooks.Add
    Set nsh = nwb.Sheets(1)

    wr.Copy
    nsh.Activate 'Pastespecial like this needs to use an active sheet (according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.pastespecial)
    ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:=1, Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False

    Dim oILS As Shape 'Thanks Beek! :)
    Set oILS = nsh.Shapes(nsh.Shapes.Count)

    With oILS
        .PictureFormat.CropLeft = 100
        .PictureFormat.CropTop = 100
        .PictureFormat.CropRight = 100
        .PictureFormat.CropBottom = 100
    End With
    With oILS
        .LockAspectRatio = True
    '    .Height = 260
    '    .Width = 450
    End With

    nwb.SaveAs (excel_path & "\" & Replace(f.Name, ".pdf", ".xlsx"))

    doc.Close True
    nwb.Close True

Next

wa.Quit
End Sub
```

This does crop my one picture. This does insert it without a background tho, so you need to change it to white later if that is needed. Also, this is going to give some prompts which would need to be dealt with, if someone else wants to adopt this code later I mean.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your answer. It is much appreciated, really. I adjusted my code and when I ran it I get the following error: Type mismatch  on this line Set oILS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Shapes.Count).

Comment: Basically, the code is converting PDF to Word as Image and then grabs the image from Word Document and pastes it to Excel, where it has to be cropped down. The VBA code is running on Excel.

Comment: @Nytro: is `oILS` still declared as an `InlineShape`? Because that would give a type mismatch

Comment: Ohh sorry, yeah ofc. That was the one I ran on my end. Lemme adjust it. I feel stupid.

Comment: @Beek yeah that coulda been the problem too. I thought that its because I was referencing the sheet that the macro runs on and then sheet one, but it is creating a new sheet and we need to reference that sheet. which he declared as "nsh" before. so referencing the first shape on nsh should do the trick

Comment: @Nytro give this a spin.

Comment: @Beek yes it is, that's where the Type mismatch comes from I guess...

Comment: @Czeskleba Thank you so much for adjusting it. How should the oILS be defined as ? It still gives a type mismatch though when I gave it the spin on this line: Set oILS = nsh.Shapes(1)

Comment: @Nytro Beek had the right idea! I simply read over the error msg. Sorry. `Dim oILS As Shape` should make it work.

Comment: @Czeskleba Thank you! That did the trick on it indeed. However it now shows a different error: "The index to the specified collection is out of bounds" on this line: Set oILS = nsh.Shapes(nsh.Shapes.Count). This happens when wr.Copy and nsh.Paste are just above nwb.SaveAs. If I put wr.Copy and nsh.Paste just above Dim oILS it gives the error "Out of bounds" on .PictureFormat.CropLeft=100, I tried setting up a smaller number <100 and it gives : "method paste of object _worksheet failed" on nsh.Paste

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207647/discussion-between-czeskleba-and-nytro).